# Handling innoDB deadlock

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, deadlock

I've been getting a `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` error on my InnoDB tables. Here is the query:

```
UPDATE views 
SET visit_cnt = visit_cnt + 1 
WHERE visit_day = DATE(NOW()) 
AND article_id = '4838'
```

This query also triggers this via ON UPDATE trigger:

```
UPDATE articles 
SET views = views + 1 
WHERE id = NEW.article.id
```

Here is how I tried to fixed it:

```
$attempts_left = 5;
do
{
    mysql_query ($query);

    // if we found a deadlock, we will try this query 4 more times   
    if (mysql_errno () == 1213) { // 1213 - deadlock error
        $deadlocked = true;
        $attempts_left --;
    }
    else{
        $deadlocked = false;
    }
}
while($deadlocked && $attempts_left > 0);
```

My question: is this the only way to handle a deadlock? I mean this is quite ugly and deadlocks happen time to time anyway. Is there any recommended way to fix deadlocks?

Comment: Is the articles table InnoDB or MyISAM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368561/php-mysql-pdoexception-deadlock-exception-code-or-alternative if you're using PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good documentation about handling [InnoDB deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html).

PS: I didn't have anything more to add so just gave you the link.

Comment: Thanks, I fallowed instructions on MySQL site. Command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS gave the big query that was causing all the troubles with locking.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to play some games with the Transaction Isolation/MVCC features

Option 1) You may want to surround the query in a begin commit block

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE views
SET visit_cnt = visit_cnt + 1
WHERE visit_day = DATE(NOW())
AND article_id = '4838';

< Any actions in the trigger would be part of the transaction >

COMMIT;
```

Option 2) You may want to disable autocommit for your session

```
SET autocommit = 0;
```

Option 3) Change the transaction isolation before launching the query to expose dirty reads

This one is a stretch !!!

```
SET tx_isolation = READ_COMMITTED;
```

or

```
SET tx_isolation = READ_UNCOMMITTED;
```

Give it a Try and let us all know !!!

Answer (score 2):

That's the proper way, as the documentation states:

> Normally, you must write your applications so that they are always prepared to re-issue a transaction if it gets rolled back because of a deadlock.

If you want to reduce the occurrence of deadlocks, you must show us the tables DDL and indexes.