# User File Uploads From Browser Slow Entire Server (web app)

Tags: php, performance, apache, innodb, myisam

**SEE THE LAST UPDATE AT THE BOTTOM FOR MY FINAL EVAL / SUGGESTIONS**

This seems so basic that it should be a common problem.. but I've already searched for anything pertaining to this issue with no luck

**-- Scenario --**

I have a web application that, as one of it's functions, allows users to upload photos to the server. File size limits aren't the issue, but i can notice a visible difference in the speed of the server when i'm uploading a file vs not.

**-- Testing --**

I uploaded a 3MB file while signed in to another account (on another computer completely) to test the page load times in firebug. Caching has been disabled. The results are below:

> Baseline page speed (without upload): 0.409, 0.449, 0.468
>
> During 3MB file upload:1.28, 8.58, --upload complete -- 0.379

This problem obviously compounds if more than one user is uploading a photo at the same time. This seems insane considering all the power i have with the current setup.

**-- Setup --**

Mediatemple DV Level 3 Application server (4GB ram, 16 cores)

Mediatemple DV Dev level 1 database server (running mysiam tables)

Cloudflare CDN

Custom PHP application

Wordpress sales website (front end, same server - not connected in any way to the web app)

CentOS 6.5

Mysql 5.5

**-- So Far --**

- I had the cloudtech team at MT tune the apache & nginx settings for me since i thought i had screwed this up, but the issue is still showing up
- I am considering changing all the DB tables to innodb for concurrency, but this is not related to the question at hand
- The server load averages do not seem to be significantly affected when uploading my test file

the output of "free -m" is below

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096        634       3461          0          0        215
-/+ buffers/cache:        419       3676
Swap:         1536         36       1499
```

**EDIT 1**

Is it possible to offload these types of things to an independent server? I realize the PHP used to upload the file would also have to be run from that server, but at least then only the upload / long process server would be affected and not the entire application.

Also, is there any other language or workflow that would work better for this? Perl? Python?

**EDIT 2** (2014-08-28)

I forgot to mention two things

1) this issue isn't just with file uploads - it happens whenever a php script runs for an extended time. As a test, i ran a 3 minute php script on my end and sure enough, got a phone call from a client during the execution about the "slow" system.

2) I have high concurrent log in sessions running. Many of these users are likely on the same script at the same time.

Here is the output from htop. The "php-cgi" processes are the obvious offenders, but i don't know how to see which scripts are causing this load. Again, even if i did find the script, i feel like i should be able to run more than a handful of php scripts at a time.

[image: htop server load]

**EDIT 3 (2014-08-28)**

Here is the htop at peak hours (right now). What's annoying is that the system is flying at the moment with 2x the traffic and processes.
[image: htop two]

**EDIT 4 / UPDATE (2014-09-30)**

After a month of staring at this, I've found some things to be true. I'm hoping some of this will help others get their high-growth applications in check before it turns into an issue of racing traffic with server upgrades (which is what happened here).

**The Issue** I was using MyISAM as the exclusive database engine. I had read through hundreds of docs and forum posts regarding whether **InnoDB** or MyISAM is the better engine to use, most sources giving vague evaluations or (at best) overly complicated benchmarking with vague settings claiming to increase (or even decrease..?) performance. Forget it all and **USE InnoDB FOR ALL APPLICATIONS**

Find a good resource to help you tune your MySQL server settings and run with it (see links below). Apparently the concurrent traffic on the server was overloading PHP while waiting for the table locks to release in MyISAM. This was causing excessive loads on the application server, while the DB server was just hanging out with hardly any CPU or MEM load. Transitioning to InnoDB allows high-concurrency at the cost of CPU and Memory (both GOOD things, buy a bigger DB server if you have to).

In the end, the load has transferred to the DB server, increasing concurrent traffic performance. To summarize DON'T USE MyISAM ON WEB APPLICATIONS. Period. I'm sure i'll get burned a bit by saying that, but the slight performance hit (yes, MyISAM is a BIT faster at low-concurrency, but who cares if your web app crashes) is well worth the increase in concurrency.

**IMPORTANT POINTS**

1) When you move your database over to InnoDB "ALTER TABLE `my_table` SET ENGINE="InnoDB" you will need to use the info found in the following links to set your innodb specific settings.

2) Be sure to code a loop wrapper in PHP (3 iterations sounds good) for your query calls to account for deadlocks (a situation where queries are basically competing for the same row(s) and one or both are stalled completely).

3) Write your PHP to look for ERRORS coming out of your new query wrapper.

**EG:** Send the query -> Error found -> Check for deadlock -> if deadlock, retry query after waiting 0.1 sec -> check again, if error found that isn't deadlock, return error to app, else continue until iteration limit is reached (3 in this example) -> if iteration limit is hit, return error to application

Do something now that your query has failed.

**Helpful Links**

http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/

[Handling innoDB deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313870/handling-innodb-deadlock)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size

**CAUTION**
I crashed the MySQL server with the setting in the following link. You MUST completely stop mysqld (service mysqld stop) before renaming (NOT deleting) the original files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1), usually found here on RH/CentOS

**/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0**

http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

Once they are renamed, start your mysql daemon **service mysqld start**

Hopefully this helps someone,
-B

Comment: do you process the uploaded images in any way, like resize, watermark and what not? How about installing htop and watch the server processes live when doing the upload, see what exactly increases the load.

Comment: I resize all the images and save them at a more acceptable resolution for storage. I also make 2 versions of the file (reduced size / thumbnail). I will try htop and see what i can find

Comment: "I uploaded a 3MB file while signed in to another account (on another computer completely)" Was that computer on a separate network and internet connection? If they're on the same connection, you can't trust the benchmark one bit.

Comment: True, but it doesn't negate the fact that the system slows when files are going up. I was simply trying to get some numbers to back up the "feel" @ceejayoz

Comment: @BizLab Yes, it does negate the fact. Your page load times **will** be slower if another computer on your network is consuming a lot of upload. Try BitTorrenting a movie on a computer on your network - you'll find the entire internet is suddenly slower, but it's not a worldwide server slowdown, it's just your network. You need to test the load times on a network independent of the uploading device. Something like Pingdom's tools, Blitz.io, a cloud instance you create, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz i'm referring to the reduced speed / increased lag when other computers, in other states, on other isps upload photos and i feel the lag on my end. Let's let some others have at it, thanks.

Comment: @BizLab That's new information you didn't originally provide. No need to get snippy!

Comment: Just annoyed at this server, my bad @ceejayoz. Too much time wasted on this bs that could be used doing what i need to do.

Comment: I don't think it's php's fault at all, but knowing MT setup and the fact they put nginx in front of apache (actually i believe plesk does this) should give you the option to use php directly as an apache module and not as fast-cgi. So do the switch from Plesk or command line and see the difference. Btw, regarding higher CPU load and image resize, this is perfectly normal, image resizing takes lots of memory and cpu to happen.

Comment: @Twisted1919 good point. Maybe i should consider uploading raw images only and triggering a background python script to actually process the images, removing the php process connection and freeing up the browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BizLab The whole approach with resizing the images after upload is bad IMHO, what do you do after a year when you have 1M images and you need to add 10 new sizes for various sections? Going to do 10M operation of resize? I personally resize them on the fly, check if the size exists and if not resize and serve it. You could also go with a python or php cli script to do this in background, but it doesn't seem to be optimal to run such scripts, what if your queue becomes large and hangs the server? Does it worth all the continous checks for new files to feed the background app?

Comment: See second answer from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365976/file-uploads-slower-than-users-network-upload-speed-on-apache-ec2