# File uploads slower than user's network upload speed on Apache (EC2)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, performance, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running a basic LAMP stack as a webserver.  Users can upload photos through my web application which are then stored in a directory and recorded in MySQL.  Typically these upload as fast as a user's internet upload speed allows.

Unfortunately, multiple users have been reporting that sometimes photo uploads are slowing down - taking up to 2 minutes per photo, while on other sites the users are able to upload much faster.

How can I optimize Apache (I'm assuming it's Apache?) to not become a bottleneck?  Could this issue be resolved with MPM Preforking?  Or is it possibly a database locking issue?

---

Some additional stats of this setup (it's pretty vanilla):

`Instance Type: t2.small
EBS-optimized: False
PHP v5.4
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon)`

The only other thing that I'm considering relevant is that when a photo is uploaded, it's resized via Imagick to a thumbnail size (which is obviously a bit CPU intensive, but normally it's quite fast).

Comment: Are the photos the same size?

Comment: Yes.  They're photos from iPhones/Android phones - typically a few MBs - and they can upload multiple at a time.

Comment: If they are uploading from over a cellular network you are never going to hear the end of these complaints. There may be stuff you can do on your end, but you should set expectations for users/stakeholders that there will always be some variability in speed, especially upload speed.

Comment: Have you checked the resource monitor to find what the actual bottleneck is? Is it CPU, it is Network? If CPU, have you ran "top" to see what's using the CPU? I guess you're on the t2 instances: don't forget these are burst instances in which you may get more power when needed, but nothing is guaranteed, including network throughput (which is also "as available" [my term]. If you want more surety on performance, you'll need to up to a higher plan. Even then, nothing is guaranteed with AWS, but you're in a better position to provision for your bottlenecks. We'll never run production on a t2.

Comment: @JoshRumbut They're experiencing the issue uploading over wi-fi from both desktop and mobile devices, but that's a good point otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: @Robbie You make a very interesting point... Yes, it's a t2 instance. Network throughput... Is there anywhere we can see stats on the actual 'minimum' throughput guaranteed? Happy to upgrade if it would solve the issue. Would an m3 be enough in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue can be because of many reasons. But among the variables that you can control, You can start with network throttling. Basically suppose that there are ten users on your application. All with same upload speed . When they all simultaniously try to upload images. assume nine would get good speed. But because your server can only have a fixed transmission rate which all the nine guys are using, even though the tenth one is with same network performance, he will be uploading image slower. To handle this problem, you limit the speed per connection in your server, which is also called network throttling.
Configuring the same in apache could be found [here](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/download-speed-limit-and-throttling-for-apache-2-4). But again this is just a speculation and in real life there can be many factors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I'm understanding your point, you're saying that if several users are uploading all at once, someone can get the short end of the stick.  This seems to be happening when only one user is uploading, though.  Any ideas what might be causing a single user to experience slow uploads from a multi-photo upload?

Comment: @JeremyPenrod as i pointed out that the answer is only one of the many possibility. if it persists with a single user, it can be network issue or maybe some bug in program

Answer (score 0):

Lots of left out info, like what are you running, what are your specs.
First thing I would do is increase your memory via php.ini file.

set('memory_limit', '64M'); (mine is set to 256m
OR change it globally in php.ini (in Lampp located in '\lampp\php\php.ini'):

memory_limit = 8M // search for this "memory_limit" and adjust it by your needs.
After that restart apache...

REFER TO PIC. setting in yellow should be as follows.

[image]